Strange issue with Friedman pairwise post-hoc evaluation vs Wilcoxon test
I'have a dataset with 15 patient samples in medical field. The data seems to be non-normal distributing. I am planning to compare the 5 different paired measurement levels (T1 to T5) of a biomarker. So I've carried out a Friedman test in SPSS and used the pairwise comparison (pairwise among groups are conducted with bonferroni). The default pairwise comparison option in Friedman indicates that the differences in the levels at the timeline 1 and 2 (T1 ve T2) are statistically insignificant (p>0.05). However, when I compare T1 and T2 manualy with Wilcoxon signed-rank test, the result indicates the p level <0.05. I do understand that the selection of tests should be based on the actual hypothese, and that Friedman test is an omnibus test (working totaly in a different manner compared with Wilcoxon) but I'm not sure how I should report the results in my study. In my case, in your manuscript or study, how would you report the differences between T1 and T2; significant or insignificant?

There are two different possible directions of explanation here.
The first is the same explanation that you would have for a comparison of means: that it's just the multiple-comparison problem.  Perhaps your Friedman post-hoc p-value is larger because it is set to control the family-wise Type I error rate and your pairwise Wilcoxon test isn't. If that's the case, then you should decide whether you want family-wise error rate control and choose based on that decision.  One way to tell if this might be the explanation would be to apply a multiple-testing correction to the p-value from the Wilcoxon test.
The second explanation is specific to rank tests. In ANOVA post-hoc tests are comparing the same means of the same observations that a simple t-test would compare. For Friedman's test this is not true. Friedman's test assigns scores to each observation that depend on values for that specific individual in all 5 timepoints (but not on any other individuals). The Wilcoxon test assigns scores that depend on the pairwise differences for all individuals; it's not even slightly the same.
The two-group analogue of the Friedman test is the sign test, but even there the fact that scores in the sign test depend on only two timepoints and scores in the Friedman test depend on all five timepoints means that they need not agree.
If the problem is the changes in the scores then you probably want the Friedman post-hoc test since that uses the same scores as the Friedman test.
Or an ANOVA, where the problem doesn't arise

that was a great explanation, thank you. So, in my case, if i carry out an Friedman anaylsis and evaluate the pairwise comparisons with Wilcoxon, It's not a logical fallacy, or is it?
